# Trying to add while loop to this codeblock

Tags: c++, while-loop

SOLVED 11/19/2017 @ 10:20PM

This is the codeblock I'm working on, and I need to implement a while loop to run it infinitely until the user is satisfied. I'm not sure if gross_pay should be in the condition or if something else needs to be there. I keep on getting this error code. (error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'gross_pay' used)

```
// GrossPay.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//int temp = 0;
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    using namespace std;

        int main()
        {
            double hourly_rate;
            double hours;
        double gross_pay;
        while ( gross_pay >= 1 ) {
        printf("Please input the hourly rate of the employee: ");
        cin >> hourly_rate;
        printf("Please input the number of hours worked by the employee: ");
        cin >> hours;

        if (hours <= 40)
        {
            gross_pay = hours * hourly_rate;
        }
        else
        {
            gross_pay = (40 * hourly_rate) + (hours - 40) * (hourly_rate * 1.5);
        }

        cout << "The gross pay of this employee is $" << gross_pay << "." << endl;

        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

### }

Solution:

```
// GrossPay.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double hourly_rate;
    double hours;
    double gross_pay = 1;
    while (gross_pay >= 1) {
        printf("Please input the hourly rate of the employee: ");
        cin >> hourly_rate;
        printf("Please input the number of hours worked by the employee: ");
        cin >> hours;

        if (hours <= 40)
         {
             gross_pay = hours * hourly_rate;
         }
         else
         {
            gross_pay = (40 * hourly_rate) + (hours - 40) * (hourly_rate * 
1.5);
        }

        cout << "The gross pay of this employee is $" << gross_pay << "." << 
endl;


    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks to all who have commented, I have taken the advice from you all and have been working on this code-block resulting in it's success! I will post the solved work in the original post.. Thanks again for all your advice!

Answer (score 2):

Every variable should be initialized before you are using for an operation otherwise the result may not be same as you expected.

Rewrite as  `double gross_pay = 1;`

If you don't specify an initialization value then the value for  **double gross_pay**  is undefined. It will set to 0 for global variable.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says everything, you have to initialize `gross_pay` first, otherwise its value is `undefined`

```
double gross_pay = 1;
```

Or you can change `while` loop to `do-while`

```
do {
    printf("Please input the hourly rate of the employee: ");
    cin >> hourly_rate;
    .....
    .........
} while ( gross_pay >= 1 );
```